# How to make my “custom integer type” perform better?

Tags: c++, performance, bitset

During a project at my work I needed a convenient way to store values taking up the smallest amount of bits necessary, not in memory but later when they're serialized into an array of unsigned short ints. For instance, a value that could be between 0 and 7 was only supposed to be 3 bits long. I ended up developing my own solution based on std::bitset with some additional code in order to make it work with signed values. Another goal was to make it work as close to a regular integer type as possible. This is the code (https://github.com/AndersHogqvist/custom_int):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t Size>
class TypeBase {
public:
  size_t size() const {
    return data_.size();
  }

  unsigned long to_ulong() const {
    return data_.to_ulong();
  }

  unsigned long long to_ullong() const {
    return data_.to_ullong();
  }

  std::bitset<Size> data() const {
    return data_;
  }

  std::string to_string() const {
    return data_.to_string();
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator=(const T value) {
    data_ = std::bitset<Size>(value);
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator==(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    return data_ == other.data();
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator==(const T value) const {
    return data_.to_ullong() == value;
  }

  bool operator!=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator!=(const T value) const {
    return data_ != std::bitset<Size>(value);
  }

  bool operator<(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    if (data_ == other.data_) {
      return false;
    }
    return less_than_(other.data_);
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator<(const T value) const {
    return less_than_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
  }

  bool operator<=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    if (data_ == other.data_) {
      return true;
    }
    return less_than_or_eq_(other.data_);
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator<=(const T value) const {
    return less_than_or_eq_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
  }

  bool operator>(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    if (data_ == other.data_) {
      return false;
    }
    return greater_than_(other.data_);
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator>(const T value) const {
    return greater_than_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
  }

  bool operator>=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) const {
    if (data_ == other.data_) {
      return true;
    }
    return greater_than_or_eq_(other.data_);
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  bool operator>=(const T value) const {
    return greater_than_or_eq_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator+(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other.data_[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator+(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator+(const T value) {
    bool carry = false;
    std::bitset<Size> other(value);
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator+=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other.data_[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator+=(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator+=(const T value) {
    bool carry = false;
    std::bitset<Size> other(value);
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator++(int) {
    bool carry = false;
    std::bitset<Size> other(1);
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator-(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    subtract_(other.data_);
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator-(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    subtract_(other);
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator-(const T value) {
    subtract_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator-=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    subtract_(other.data_);
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator-=(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    subtract_(other);
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator-=(const T value) {
    subtract_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator--(int) {
    subtract_(std::bitset<Size>(1));
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator*(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    multiply_(other.data_);
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator*(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    multiply_(other);
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator*(const T value) {
    multiply_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator*=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    multiply_(other.data_);
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator*=(const T value) {
    multiply_(std::bitset<Size>(value));
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator/(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    data_ = data_.to_ullong() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator/(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    data_ = data_.to_ullong() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator/(const T value) {
    data_ = data_.to_ullong() / value;
    return *this;
  }

  TypeBase<Size> &operator/=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    data_ = data_.to_ullong() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  TypeBase<Size> &operator/=(const T value) {
    data_ = data_.to_ullong() / value;
    return *this;
  }

  template<size_t S>
  friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const TypeBase<S> &u);
protected:
  TypeBase() = default;
  ~TypeBase() = default;

  std::bitset<Size> data_;

  bool add_(bool b1, bool b2, bool &carry) {
    bool sum = (b1 ^ b2) ^ carry;
    carry = (b1 && b2) || (b1 && carry) || (b2 && carry);
    return sum;
  }

  void subtract_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    bool borrow = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
      if (borrow) {
        if (data_[i]) {
          data_[i] = other[i];
          borrow = other[i];
        }
        else {
          data_[i] = !other[i];
          borrow = true;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (data_[i]) {
          data_[i] = !other[i];
          borrow = false;
        }
        else {
          data_[i] = other[i];
          borrow = other[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void multiply_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    std::bitset<Size> tmp = data_;
    data_.reset();
    if (tmp.count() < other.count()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        if (tmp[i]) {
          operator+=(other << i);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        if (other[i]) {
          operator+=(tmp << i);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool less_than_or_eq_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) const {
    for (int i = Size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data_[i] && !other[i]) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!data_[i] && other[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool less_than_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) const {
    for (int i = Size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data_[i] && !other[i]) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!data_[i] && other[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool greater_than_or_eq_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) const {
    for (int i = Size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data_[i] && !other[i]) {
        return true;
      }
      if (!data_[i] && other[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool greater_than_(const std::bitset<Size> &other) const {
    for (int i = Size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data_[i] && !other[i]) {
        return true;
      }
      if (!data_[i] && other[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

template<size_t Size>
class Int : public TypeBase<Size> {
public:
  Int() = default;

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  Int(const T value) {
    TypeBase<Size>::operator=(value);
  }

  ~Int() = default;

  Int<Size> &operator=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    if (this->data_ == other.data()) {
      return *this;
    }
    this->data_ = other.data();
    return *this;
  }

  long long to_int() const {
    if (this->data_[Size - 1]) {
      std::bitset<Size> tmp = this->data_;
      tmp.flip();
      return tmp.to_ullong() * -1 - 1;
    }
    return this->data_.to_ullong();
  }

  Int<Size> &operator/(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    this->data_ = to_int() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  Int<Size> &operator/(const std::bitset<Size> &other) {
    this->data_ = to_int() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  Int<Size> &operator/(const T value) {
    this->data_ = to_int() / value;
    return *this;
  }

  Int<Size> &operator/=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    this->data_ = to_int() / other.to_ullong();
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  Int<Size> &operator/=(const T value) {
    this->data_ = to_int() / value;
    return *this;
  }
};

template<size_t Size>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Int<Size> &u) {
  out << u.to_int();
  return out;
}

template<size_t Size>
class UInt : public TypeBase<Size> {
public:
  UInt() = default;

  template<typename T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  UInt(const T value) {
    TypeBase<Size>::operator=(value);
  }

  ~UInt() = default;

  UInt<Size> &operator=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    if (this->data_ == other.data()) {
      return *this;
    }
    this->data_ = other.data();
    return *this;
  }

  unsigned long long to_int() const {
    return this->data_.to_ullong();
  }
};

template<size_t Size>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const UInt<Size> &u) {
  out << u.to_ullong();
  return out;
}
```

Here are some examples on how it's supposed to be used:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "custom_int.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Int<13> test1 = 1;
  UInt<5> test2;

  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;
  cout << "test2: " << test2 << endl;

  test1++;
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;

  test1--;
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;

  test1 -= 10;
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;

  auto test3 = test1;

  cout << "test3: " << test3 << endl;

  test3 /= 3;

  cout << "test3: " << test3 << endl;

  test2 += 20;

  cout << "test2: " << test2 << endl;

  test2 = test2 / 10;

  cout << "test2: " << test2 << endl;
}
```

I'm by no means a seasoned C++ developer, so even if I believe it's working the way it should I would love to have some input on what can be improved.

What I'm mostly concerned about is the performance (unnecessary copying etc). It's supposed to be used in a real time application so I need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Is it intended to work for integers wider than `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @harold, in my project I was handling up to 64 bit unsigned ints, so i haven't really thought about anything larger than that.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Editing code _after_ the answer was posted is against the CR policy, because it invalidates the answer.

Comment: sorry for that @vnp

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. If your code has significantly improved, preferably with edits of yourself as well, you could ask a new question, a follow-up.

Comment: I apologize for that! I will read the rules carefully and try to stick to them from now on!

Answer (score 5):

A significant performance drain is bit-by-bit computation loops such as

```
  TypeBase<Size> &operator+=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < Size; ++ix) {
      data_[ix] = add_(data_[ix], other.data_[ix], carry);
    }
    return *this;
  }
```

Unfortunately, at this time such constructs are not recognized by [major compilers](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZHDPZk), and probably also not by various embedded compilers (which if I recall correctly you mentioned earlier).

For small `Size` it could be implemented with plain old arithmetic operators,

```
  TypeBase<Size> &operator+=(const TypeBase<Size> &other) {
    data_ = std::bitset<Size>(to_ullong() + other.to_ullong());
    return *this;
  }
```

Which unsurprisingly compiles to normal addition.

Larger `Size` is trickier to support efficiently this way.

Comment: This is exactly why I posted it here! Thank you for your input, much appreciated. Would it be sufficient if I added a control statement that implements your solution if ```Size <= 64``` and if not use the current bit-by-bit function?

Comment: @Zenit_swe that would do it, though it's a very sharp performance discontinuity between 64 and 65 bits then